# Expansion of ${n+3-1 \choose 3}$

Tags: combinatorics

$${n+3-1 \choose 3}$$

Can someone help me with the factorial expansion of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $n+3-1=n+2$.

Comment: Is it $\frac{(n+2)!}{(3!)(n-1)!}$?

Comment: That is correct, but with a $3$ in the lower position you might want an expression that does not involve factorials.  You should be able to find one with a cubic polynomial in $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: Simplifying it to $\frac{1}{6} (n)(n+1)(n+2)$?

Answer (score 3):

By definition:
$${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
So:

$${n+3-1\choose 3}={n+2\choose 3}=\frac{(n+2)!}{3!(n+2-3)!}=\frac{(n+2)!}{3!(n-1)!}\;\;\;\;\;\left(=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{6}\right)$$
Like MathyMatherson already said in the comments!